# Yii2 - Return empty API response

Tags: php, yii2

Basic question. But how should I return an empty response with **response code 200** in **Yii2**?

Pretty sure the answer will be straightforward, but I've been looking for the answer to this basic question and can't find any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the response object

```
Yii::$app->response->setStatusCode(200)->send()
```